# db.getCollection(...).find(...).aggregate is not a function

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, robo3t

(* MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12 *)

I have a collection `logs` and a collection `users`. `logs` has a field `userId` which represents the user who sent the log. `users` has a field `_id`.

I use Robo 3T to undertake queries to data in remote server.

Now, I'm interested in the logs whose `url` is `/subscribe`, and I want to see those user information behind. So I write the following query:

```
db.getCollection('logs').find({ "url" : "/subscribe" }).aggregate({
    $lookup:{
        from:"users",
        localField:"userId",
        foreignField:"_id",
        as:"logs_users"
    }
})
```

But I get an error:

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this?

**Edit 1:** I got a new error:

[image]

Comment: What Mongo version is the server? `$lookup` was introduced in Mongo 3.2

Comment: `MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12` in the server.

Comment: 2.6.12 does not support the `$lookup` stage.

Comment: There is no other alternative functions in 2.6.12?

Comment: I don't believe so. The whole concept of joining is not natural in Mongo.

Comment: Please don't paste images. User formatted text for code and error message.

Answer (score 1):

You should not but use aggregate after the find, instead, use aggregate directly and use **$match** operator to find the documents and then **$lookup**

```
db.getCollection('logs').aggregate([
   {
       $match:{"url" : "/subscribe"}
   },
   {
       $lookup:{
        from:"users",
        localField:"userId",
        foreignField:"_id",
        as:"logs_users"
       }
   }
])
```

**Update: To use $lookup your MongoDB version should be equal or greater than 3.2, as this operator(joins) don't work in older versions of MongoDB**

Comment: Which MongoDB version are you using? try mongod --version

Comment: `MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12` in the server

Comment: So, I should upgrade my mongodb or look for other workaround of $lookup?

Comment: $lookup operator was introduced in MongoDB version 3.2, the database version you are using is quite old, yes you should update the DB version if you want to do that with MongoDB query, Otherwise, you can do that join manually in your respective coding language

Comment: Another workaround is that I can copy data to my local disk and query it where more recent mongodb is installed, right?

Comment: Yes, technically it is possible to do that but that's overhead, you can try that